# How do I cast between string and symbol in KDB Q?

Tags: kdb

If I've got a symbol `MSFT and I want to get a string "MSFT", I thought I'd be able to do:

```
`string$`MSFT
```

but this doesn't work.

I had also expected the opposite to be true, that I would be able to:

```
`$"MSFT"
```

and be returned `MSFT, but this doesn't seem to work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to string a symbol.

```
q)string`MSFT
"MSFT"
```

Your syntax for casting to symbol looks correct to me - not sure what the issue is on your end.

```
q)`$"MSFT"
`MSFT
```